# Can I marry my niece, is it allowed in Islam

Tags: nikah

Assalamualaikum . Iam a Muslim and I love a girl . She is my relative . My father's sister's son's daughter. She is my niece.but she not my real niece . Like hazart Ali and Bibi Fatima also have same relationship they were allowed by allah. And my niece is half year big then me plz any one answered it's really very important to me and my life

Answer (score 1):

If your father's sister had a daughter, she would be permissible to marry, as she is NOT your Mahram. So a cousin's daughter is obviously permissible to marry as she is not a Mahram either.